# Retrieve values from listview using without id

Tags: android, listview

my application having a List view.....How can i retrieve specified field value....(in my case nickname and body.see database)???????i mean that i will pope out nickname and body text from listView....How can it possible

my code ListView.java

```
public class ListView extends ListActivity {

SQLiteDatabase messagedb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_list);



    messagedb=ListView.this.openOrCreateDatabase("message",0, null);
    messagedb.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab2(" +
            " _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            " nickname varchar,sender INT(13),body varchar)");

    Cursor cur = messagedb.rawQuery("select rowid as _id, nickname, body from tab2", null);
    String[] from = new String[] { "nickname", "body" };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.sender_entry, R.id.body_entry};

    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.my_list_entry, cur, from, to);

    this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    messagedb.close();


}

}
```

my demo list view as follows

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood right. It will be your solution.

```
   @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String nickName = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sender_entry))
                .getText().toString();
        String BODY = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.body_entry)).getText()
                .toString();
    }
```

Comment: u mean `protected void onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
     String nickName = v.findViewById(R.id.sender_entry).getContext().toString();
     String BODY = v.findViewById(R.id.body_entry).getContext().toString();
     

 }`

Comment: String nickName = v.findViewById(R.id.sender_entry).getContext().toString();

Comment: I have edit my answer! You just need to cast the View in TextView. My bad...:)